# trivial query very slow on primary key on a PostgreSQL DB (instantaneous on MySQL)

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, primary-key

I have a table `data`:

- with ~ 400 million rows
- with `data.id` as **int4**, **not null**, and set as **primary key**
- it's an aws RDS server, with ~128G of RAM
- there are no row with id > 1e9

This query:

```
select count(*) from data where id > 1e9;
```

that returns 0, takes consistently ~ 25s to run.
It uses to take up more than 2mns (I may have run `analyze data` during my investigations and then the time dropped to 25s).

On another server, an aws aurora Postgres with the exact same table, it takes ~ 3m30s.

Anyway the same query takes a few ms on a MySQL DB, as it should.
I am very new to Postgres, so I am probably missing something obvious.

**explain analyze select count(*) from data where id > 1e9;**

```
QUERY PLAN
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=11944927.24..11944927.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23986.851..23988.183 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=11944927.03..11944927.24 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=23986.779..23988.177 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=11943927.03..11943927.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23984.078..23984.079 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using data_pkey on data  (cost=0.57..11804489.05 rows=55775191 width=0) (actual time=23984.074..23984.075 rows=0 loops=3)
                    Filter: ((id)::numeric > '1000000000'::numeric)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 133840000
                    Heap Fetches: 100863313
Planning Time: 0.078 ms
Execution Time: 23988.219 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You should always include **full** table definitions with any questions - the more detail you provide in your quesiton, the better chance you have of obtaining good answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have an index on `id`.  If not, you need one.

Your problem is the `1e9`. If you write a numeric constant with the scientific notation, it is considered to be of type `numeric`:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(1e9);
 pg_typeof 
═══════════
 numeric
(1 row)
```

So PostgreSQL has to cast `id` to type `numeric` to perform the comparison (the `(id)::numeric` in your execution plan) and cannot use the index.

Using a constant of type `integer` should speed up processing:

```
select count(*) from data where id > 1000000000;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Now it takes ~ 150ms. I knew there had to be some reason. And that may also explain some other issue I have using a timestamp wo tz field.